# Document will not compile any more tikzpictures in Texstudio or Overleaf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, compiling

My 17-page document will not compile when I add anymore tikzpictures to the document, and I can't figure out why. I use TexStudio. If I comment out the second to last tikzpicture in the code below, it will compile. All the pictures will compile if I only include the packages needed to produce the tikzpictures, which is what I normally do to test tikz drawings before I copy and paste them over to my main documents. I put most of the packages that I'm using in the example below.

I also copied and pasted this into an Overleaf document and I got some type of warning about the scrextend package, so I removed it. But it still won't compile. I don't get any error messages in Texstudio; it just stays frozen until I force it to stop compiling. I use these same packages in this same order for documents that are 90+ pages and with a whole lot more tikzpictures, and those documents compile. So, I'm at a lost here.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,psfrag,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning,patterns}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
%    filecolor=magenta,  
    urlcolor=red,
}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{commath,mathtools,enumitem,bbm,empheq,cases,wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx,yfonts,color,soul,fancyhdr,framed}
\usepackage{combelow,microtype,flexisym,wasysym,stmaryrd}
\usepackage[small,bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{belowskip=2pt}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\Large\scshape}
    {\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{0.2cm}{\addperiod}
\newcommand{\addperiod}[1]{#1.}

\setlist[enumerate]{label=\arabic*.),itemsep=3pt,topsep=0pt,leftmargin=36pt,parsep=8pt}
%\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\alph.*)}
\renewcommand\labelitemi{$\RHD$}



\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    xticklabels={,,},
    yticklabels={,,,},
    xlabel={$Re$},
    xlabel style={xshift=1.75cm},
    ylabel={$Im$},
    ylabel style={xshift=0.45cm,yshift=1.3cm},
    xmin=-1.5,
    xmax=3.75,
    ymin=-3.25,
    ymax=3.25,
    ]
    \addplot[mark=none,thick,color=blue,domain=0:3,style=-{Triangle[length=2mm,width=1.5mm]}] {.95*x} node[above] {$z$};
    \addplot[mark=none,line width=0.04cm, dashed, color=red,domain=0:2.95] {0} node[below,xshift=-1cm] {$a$};
    \addplot +[mark=none,color=red,dashed] coordinates {(2.95, 0) (2.95, 2.95*.95)} node[anchor=west,yshift=-1cm] {$b$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \caption{$z = a + ib \in \mathbb{C}$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$} \label{fig:zlength}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    xticklabels={,,},
    yticklabels={,,,},
    xlabel={$Re$},
    xlabel style={xshift=1.75cm},
    ylabel={$Im$},
    ylabel style={xshift=0.45cm,yshift=1.3cm},
    xmin=-1.5,
    xmax=3.75,
    ymin=-3.25,
    ymax=3.25,
    ]
    \addplot[mark=none,thick,color=blue,domain=0:2,style=-{Triangle[length=2mm,width=1.5mm]}] {.5*x} node[above,yshift=-0.7cm] {$z_1$};
    \addplot[mark=none,thick,color=cyan,domain=0:1,style=-{Triangle[length=2mm,width=1.5mm]}] {2*x} node[above,xshift=0.4cm] {$z_1 + z_2$};
    \addplot[mark=none,domain=-1:0,color=blue,style={Triangle[length=2mm,width=1.5mm]}-] {-x} node[above,xshift=-1.4cm,yshift=0.2cm] {$z_2$};
    \addplot[mark=none,dashed,domain=1:2,color=blue,style={Triangle[length=2mm,width=1.5mm]}-] {3-x} node[above,xshift=-0.1cm,yshift=0.2cm] {$z_2$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \caption{$z_1, z_2, z_1 + z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$} \label{fig:Cvectoradd}
\end{subfigure} \caption{Vector representation of $\mathbb{C}$}
\end{figure}

\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\vspace{-5cm}
\begin{align*}
    r &= \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \\[1.5em]
    \theta &= \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \\[1.5em]
    z &= r \cos\theta + ir \sin\theta \\
    &= re^{i\theta}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    xticklabels={,,},
    yticklabels={,,,},
    xlabel={$Re$},
    xlabel style={anchor=north west,xshift=-0.3cm,yshift=-0.2cm},
    ylabel={$Im$},
    ylabel style={xshift=0.1cm},
    xmin=-1.25,
    xmax=3.75,
    ymin=-1.25,
    ymax=4.25,
    ]
    \addplot[mark=none,line width=0.03cm,color=blue,domain=0:3,style=-{Triangle[length=2mm,width=1.5mm]}] {.95*x} node[above,pos=0.5,yshift=0.25cm] {$r$};
    \addplot[mark=none,line width=0.04cm, dashed, color=red,domain=0:2.97] {0} node[below,xshift=-1cm] {$x$};
    \addplot +[mark=none,color=red,dashed] coordinates {(2.997, 0) (2.97, 2.97*.95)} node[anchor=west,yshift=-1cm] {$y$};
    \addplot[mark=none,thick,color=black,dashed,domain=1.45:2] {(4 - x^2)^0.5} node[above,pos=0.5,xshift=0.2cm] {$\theta$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} \captionof{figure}{Polar representation of $\mathbb{C}$} \label{fig:polarrep}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.)]
\item An arbitrary open region

\hl{PICTURES, p. 10}

\item The open unit disc, $\mathbb{D} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} ~|~ |z| < 1\}$

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);
    \draw[pattern color=red,pattern=north west lines,dashed] (0,0) circle (1.25cm);
    \draw[thick,<->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[below,xshift=-0.35cm] {$Re$};
    \draw[thick,<->] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[right,yshift=-0.3cm] {$Im$};
    \node at (1.15,1.4) {$|z| = 1$};
    \node at (1.42,-0.25) {$1$};
    \node at (-1.63,-0.25) {$-1$};
    \node at (-0.18,1.52) {$i$};
    \node at (-0.32,-1.5) {$-i$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\item The annulus $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C} ~|~ 1 < |z| < 2\}$

%\begin{center}
%\begin{tikzpicture}
%   \draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);
%   \draw[dashed,pattern color=red,pattern=north west lines] (0,0) circle (1.25cm);
%   \draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle (0.65cm);
%   \draw[thick,<->] (-2,0) -- (2,0);
%   \draw[thick,<->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[above=0.1cm];
%   \node at (0.26,0.3) {$|z| = 1$};
%   \node at (1.15,1.05) {$|z| = 2$};
%\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{center}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! The issue seems to be that one of the very many packages you load does something to `|`. Do you *need* all these packages?

Comment: Thanks! More or less, yes. Can you name which packages use ``|`` that might be a problem? I'm removing ``flexisym`` but having some issues with the use of ``\frac``, so I'll try to get back with you.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. So, removing ``flexisym`` has made it compile. I can't remember why I used that package, so hopefully as I continue the document, I still won't need it. Thanks again!

Comment: flexisym is a sub package of breqn and both are a highly experimental re-implementation of tex math handling, they are by design incompatible with everything else. Fine to use for experiments but they are not expected to work in production code alongside other packages.

Comment: I would not use commath (it is based on a misunderstanding of tex math mode)

Comment: Thanks David for the suggestions. I removed those packages and my documents are compiling much faster now. A great help.